# What is the proper timing for dexamethasone injections to improve the healing of damaged tendons in humans?

Tags: tendinopathy, tendons, tendinitis, corticosteroids, dexamethasone

{1} found via experiments on rats that:

> Dexamethasone given days 5–9 leads to an increased force at failure on mechanical testing.

{2}, which commented on {1}, noted that:

> "It's well-known that corticosteroids inhibit healing, but we show that it can actually have a strong positive effect on the healing of tendons. The timing is crucial," says Per Aspenberg, professor emeritus in the Department of Clinical and Experimental Medicine at Linköping University, Sweden.

What is the proper timing for [dexamethasone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dexamethasone) injections to improve the healing of damaged tendons in humans? (Never is a valid answer, in case dexamethasone injections only work on rats)

---

References:

- {1} Parmis Blomgran, Malin Hammerman, Per Aspenberg. Systemic corticosteroids improve tendon healing when given after the early inflammatory phase. Scientific Reports, 2017; 7 (1) http://dx.doi.org/10.1038/s41598-017-12657-0 (open access)
- {2} Linköping University. "Corticosteroids aid healing -- if the timing is right." ScienceDaily. ScienceDaily, 17 October 2017. https://www.sciencedaily.com/releases/2017/10/171017110114.htm

Comment: I have not seen this done.  I had always understood one of the risks of corticosteroid injections was tendon rupture.  The mechanisms for this aren't fully understood but as mentioned in the article "The clinical effect of tendon repair for tendon spontaneous rupture after corticosteroid injection in hands" with "significant side effects have been reported as tendon degeneration and rupture.[8–11] It can inhibit tendon repair, delay tendon sheath healing, and produce tendon degeneration.[12] Collagen fragmentation and biomechanical changes may be the possible causes."